# Android - Check if device has native Facebook app

Tags: android, facebook

It's possible, from Facebook SDK, check if the device have the Facebook app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) and check if there is a launch intent for Facebook using the [getLauncHintentForPackage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage%28java.lang.String%29) method. You can provide this method with a package-name, for facebook this is `com.facebook.katana`.

Comment: But the SDK emulate the login session if the device doesn't have the Facebook app installed, and otherside it open the native app, so I guess the SDK have a method to check this out.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. You can in fact check very easily by using the way I described.